# git pr - after pull showing other changes that are already in target branch within the pr as new changes

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

TDLR:
PRs showing your changes + other team members changes instead of showing only your changes in the PR (after solving conflicts locally with git pull)

STEPS TO RECREATE THE ISSUE:

1. on master branch => `git checkout -b "feature"`
2. do your feature (while other team member pushes is code to the same area)
3. `git pull origin master` (to get the changes and solve the conflicts)
4. `git push origin/feature` and open a PR

EXPECTED RESULT:
git PR should show **your** changes only

ACTUAL RESULT:
git PR shows your changes + **the other team member changes that already in master branch**

here is my git config:

```
init.defaultbranch=main
branch.autosetuprebase=always
branch.master.rebase=true
branch.upstream.rebase=true
pull.rebase=true
rebase.autostash=true
```

how can I solve this issue?

Comment: **1.** After `git checkout feature` the command `git pull origin master` not only updates `master` bu also rebases `feature` on top of `master`; are you sure you want that? **2.** Wrong syntax in `git push origin/feature`; correct: `git push origin feature`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A safer sequence of commands would be:

```bash
# work on feature branch
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
git push -u origin feature
```

If the target of your PR is `master`, only your commits should be visible.